# jQuery .append generated inputs do not return any value.

Tags: jquery, html

I have a script that is supposed to show one text input field when loaded, with a button that allows the user to create another text input field when clicked, I managed to do this via jQuery and it works like charm. However, it seems that the new inputs generated by the .append command do not work like normal inputs, I can't fetch their values via jQuery, detect changes... Etc.

Here is an example of what I am trying to explain:

HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="" value=""><br>
</div>
<input type="button" name="" value="New input" id="new">
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $("#new").click(function() {
    $("div").append("<input type='text' name='' value=''>");
  });

$("input[type=text]").change(function() {
  alert("Input changed");
 });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qnU9w/

As you can see if you type anything in the first input it will alert "Input changed message".
But if you create a new input via the "New input" button and type something in it, it won't detect the change, and nothing will be alerted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler is only bound to elements that exist in the DOM at the point of execution.

To listen to newly created elements, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to listen for text type input elements that exist in the doucment instead:

```
$(document).on('change', "input[type=text]", function() {
    alert("Input changed");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnU9w/2/)

Edit: This is the [delegated method](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) (instead of direct).

Comment: +1 for delegation. This is the right way to contemplate present and future elements.

Comment: Thank you very much good sir, I believe this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Once you append a new element to the DOM you have to attach an event to it again, like so:

```
$(function(){

    $("#new").click(function() {
        $("div").append("<input type='text' name='' value=''>").on("change", function() {alert("Input Changed!") });

    });

    $("input[type=text]").change(function() {
      alert("Input changed");
      });
});
```

There are cleaner ways of doing it, like separating the function and attaching the function itself, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Please elaborate, I really need a proper way because using the way you  described above is going to be quite messy because the script has a lot of calculations and inputs, the one I used above is just an example.

Comment: The above answer is the more elegant way of doing it and it appears you accepted his answer. I was just trying to get a cross that whenever you append a new element to the DOM, you will have to attach a new event handler to it or else it will never fire. The above answer, the event listener is attached to the document, which means it will always be listening to changes on the DOM.